# how to sketch paths (contour integrals)

Tags: complex-analysis

How do I sketch something like this?
$$\gamma(t)=1+e^{i(\pi-t)}, 0\leq t \leq \pi$$

What would my axis be? The argand or gamma against t?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a semi-circular arc of a circle of radius 1 centered at the point $1 \in \mathbb{C}$.  It starts at the origin and makes it's way to $2 \in \mathbb{C}$ in the region where $Im(z) > 0$.